# jQuery Validate - how to ignore inline pattern validation

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jquery-validate

I have setup, where three separate goals need to be achieved:

1. Client-side validation (this is done using the jQuery Validate plugin)
2. Neat numeric formatting (this is done using the jQuery autoNumeric plugin)
3. iPad/iPhone keyboard popping up on numeric-only fields (this is done using the pattern="[0-9]*" attribute on input elements - I cannot use HTML5 type="number", because autoNumeric plugin does not support it).

The problem is, that while it works, the validate plugin raises errors for floating point values (*Invalid format*), as the decimal separator does not match the pattern="[0-9]*" regexp. Below please find a sample input field:

```
<input type="text" id="acme" name="acme" size="4" 
 data-autonumeric="{vMin: '0.00'}" class="required number autoNumeric" 
 min="0.0" step="0.01" pattern="[0-9*]">
```

Is there a way to somehow disable the pattern validation, best globally, for all validated fields, or alternatively per field? Or perhaps there is another way to force numeric keypad on iPad/iPhone, that does not imply type="number" or pattern="[0-9*]"?

**EDIT:**

I found a way around this issue, please see my answer below. If anyone has a better idea, please share. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by overriding the pattern validation method in jQuery Validate. If anyone knows a better solution, please comment.

Here is the code. It works with the jQuery.validator.addMethod("pattern"... added (ignores \d* - to display a numeric keyboard in iOS, one may set the value of the pattern attribute to "[0-9]*" or "\d*", which I use (source http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). Comment out that line to see the issue in action.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autoNumeric-1.7.4.js"></script>
<form id="test">
<input type="text" id="acme" name="acme" size="4" data-autonumeric="{vMin: '0.00'}"
    class="required number autoNumeric" min="0.0" step="0.01" pattern="\d*" value="1.00">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").validate();
    });

    // This overrides the additional-methods.min.js implementation to ignore pattern="\d*" validation
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("pattern", function (e, t, n) {
        return this.optional(t) || n == "\\d*" ? !0 : (typeof n == "string" && (n = new RegExp("^(?:" + n + ")$")), n.test(e))
    }, "Invalid format.");
</script>
```

Comment: I think that is the best solution :D